# CATransform3D: Calculate height after perspective transform

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

I have a layer with a height of 50, and I'm rotating it about the x axis. . . How can I calculate the height as the rotation proceeds?

```
CATransform3D subLayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 0);
subLayerTransform.m34 = -1 / 1800; //How does height relate to perspective and angle?
subLayerTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(subLayerTransform, 0, 0, 0);
subLayerTransform = CATransform3DRotate(subLayerTransform, 45 * (M_PI / 180), 1, 0, 0);
_transitionLayer.sublayerTransform = subLayerTransform;
```

Comment: It is sin(alpha)*length + cos(alpha)*height .

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is alpha, height and lenght? Can you make height the subject of the equation? If height is 50, with no rotation, what is height after 45 degrees rotation?

Comment: It is: new_height= sin(50)*_transitionLayer.bounds.size.width + cos(50)*_transitionLayer.bounds.size.height .

Comment: Thanks, but I still couldn't make that work. . . Refreshed my memory of the formulas, and provided an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To rotate about the y axis**

- y' = y*cos q - z*sin q
- z' = y*sin q + z*cos q
- x' = x

And the height is y1 - y0. Therefor to calculate the new y1 and y0:

```
CGFloat y0 = 0;
CGFloat y1 = 50;
CGFloat z = -1800; //This relates to the m34 perspective matrix.

y0 = y0 * cos(radians(45)) - z * sin(radians(45));
y1 = y1 * cos(radians(45)) - z * sin(radians(45));

CGFloat newHeight = y1 - y0;
```

Comment: If the .m34 is not 0, the newHeight actually is not y1 - y0, it's slightly shorter than y1 - y0. Because perspective effect make the height display on screen shorter.